AuthenticationMiddleware seems log twice a result
I use ASP.NET Core 8. I use a custom authentication handler which redacted code is:
protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync() 
{
    /**/
    bool isValidToken = false;

    if (!isValidToken) 
    {
        Logger.LogInformation($"invalid token: {token}");
        return AuthenticateResult.Fail($"Not authorized token: {token}");
    }
    /**/
}

The handler is set as follows:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(o => {
    //o.DefaultScheme = SecretKeyAuthenticationHandler.SchemeName;
}).AddScheme<SecretKeyAuthenticationOptions, SecretKeyAuthenticationHandler>(
    SecretKeyAuthenticationHandler.SchemeName, 
    o => {
        o.TokenName = conf["AppSettings:TokenName"] ?? "X-Auth-Token";
});

the pipe is built as follows:
var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) 
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

And the controller is decorated as follows:
[ApiController]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = SecretKeyAuthenticationHandler.SchemeName)]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase 
{
}

When I emit a non authenticated GET I see the following logs:
invalid token: ***
SecretKeyScheme was not authenticated. Failure message: Not authorized token: ***
SecretKeyScheme was not authenticated. Failure message: Not authorized token: ***
AuthenticationScheme: SecretKeyScheme was challenged.

The fact that invalid token: *** is logged only once seems to prove that HandleAuthenticateAsync() is only called once.
First I believe that this double logging may come from the default scheme so I comment it. But the behavior remains the same.
So I try to debug in the ASP.NET Core sources and it seems that the second logging may come from a PolicyEvaluator.
My question is: why do I twice get this error

SecretKeyScheme was not authenticated. Failure message: Not authorized token: ***

Is there a way to avoid this double logging?

Just to check, you put a breakpoint on that log and double return statement to confirm it is only being hit once?

@BenMatthews, the log occurs in dotnet code, not in my code. If I set a custom logging provider and put a breakpoint on the Log function of said custom logger, then the breakpoint is hit twice.
